# Generate libpython*.so on MacOS using pyenv

Tags: python, macos, darwin

I need to know how to generate shared lib like libpython*.so on MacOS (Darwin) using pyenv

I tried `env PYTHON_CONFIGURE_OPTS="--enable-shared" pyenv install 3.11`
But it didn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To generate a shared library like libpython*.so on MacOS (Darwin) using pyenv, you can follow the steps below:

1- Install the Xcode command line tools by running the following command in your terminal:

```
xcode-select --install
```

2- Install the latest version of OpenSSL using Homebrew by running the following commands in your terminal:

```
 brew update
 brew install openssl
```

3- Set the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable to include the OpenSSL libraries by running the following command in your terminal:

```
export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=$(brew --prefix openssl)/lib/pkgconfig
```

4-Set the PYTHON_CONFIGURE_OPTS environment variable to include the --enable-shared flag by running the following command in your terminal:

```
export PYTHON_CONFIGURE_OPTS="--enable-shared"
```

5- Install the desired version of Python using pyenv by running the following command in your terminal:

```
pyenv install <version>
```

Note: Replace  with the desired version of Python, for example, 3.11.0.

After following these steps, you should be able to generate a shared library like libpython*.so on MacOS (Darwin) using pyenv.